# Creating Kernel using Julia

Tags: kaggle

I'm very new here, trying to create kernel using Julia language, but looks the only options I've are Python and R, I even tried to uploaded existing Jupyter file created for using Julia, but it got uploaded as Python!

how can I create the kernel using Julia?

I posted the same at [Kaggle discussion](https://www.kaggle.com/getting-started/63895)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We don't currently support Julia in Kaggle Kernels.